# Twitching after Intense Workouts

Tags: bodybuilding, muscle-mass, shoulders

I do high intensity training to build mass. I usually get muscle twitching after a hardcore training session. Usually in my Glutes, Triceps, Shoulders, Chest and Quads. I am genetically more gifted with my shoulders and back - but I have never gotten any muscle twitching in my back.

My last training was a shoulder training composed of several supersets. My shoulders were so pumped it felt as if lactic acid was going to ooze out of them. About four hours after my training my [anterior deltoid](http://mymusclepassion.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/deltoidheads.jpg) started twitching. It has been doing this for about 18 hours now and almost prevented me from sleeping.

I don't think it's related to stretching because I stretch a lot (I'm a male and can do the splits easily). I'm extremely flexible and use great caution when stretching and lifting. I prefer quality over quantity.

What makes the muscle twitch? Does it mean it is overworked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many potential causes for involuntary muscle twitching (see [here](http://www.nativeremedies.com/ailment/involuntary-muscle-twitches-fasciculations.html)).
My guess is that you might just be **dehydrated**. I get involuntary twitch in my calf if I do not hydrate well during long cycling rides.

*Note*: that I'm not advocating your purchase any of the remedies in the link provided. It just contains a handy list of potential causes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that ... I drink from 3-6 litres of water per day. I got several opinions from the trainers at the gym and they seem to think the muscle is just overused and pushed too hard.

Comment: Stop pushing so hard then ;p .. that's your answer!

Comment: The other thing to check is magnesium deficiency. A friend of mine had issues with spasm and cramping relating to it.

Answer (score 0):

**It is normal** It is muscle probably a combination of fatigue/nervous_system overload/glycogen(blood sugar and electrolyte)_depletion.

I have had this all my life after very intense workout, or after games of basketball or football, or even after running or hiking very far or fast .

If I rehydrate with gatorade , and i sleep, and i wait 4-6 hours, all twitching goes away.  Very rarely will continue for up to 12-24 hours but this is a random twitching of one muscle, not random muscles twitching randomly.